# Выдаёт пустой список, при запросе на https://steamcommunity.com/search/users/

Tags: python, requests

Выдаёт пустой список пользователей, если же открыть ссылку в браузере то список пользователей будет. В steam web api такого запроса не существует, поэтому приходится так, к selenium прибегать не хочется, а остальные способы я не знаю. Как настроить запрос чтобы получить получить список пользователей, если нет такой возможности, тогда какие есть альтернативы?

```
def search_for_steamid_by_nickname(nickname, page=2):
    user_agent = UserAgent()

    session = requests.session()
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}
    session.get('https://steamcommunity.com/', headers=headers)
    print('; '.join([f'{key}={value}' for key, value in session.cookies.items()]))
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36', 'Cookie': '; '.join([f'{key}={value}' for key, value in session.cookies.items()])}
    response = requests.get(f'https://steamcommunity.com/search/users/', headers=headers, params={'text': nickname})
    print(response.status_code)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    users = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'searchPersonaName'})
    print(users)

search_for_steamid_by_nickname('123123123')
```

Comment: Наверно потому, что нужные данные получаются через API при помощи JS, а не хранятся в HTML страницы...? Я конечно не знаком с питоном, слышал вроде, что он умеет рендерить перед тем, как отдать результат, но как бы, зачем? Жмете F12, обновляете страницу, видите там один запрос, примерно такого содержимого: `/search/SearchCommunityAjax?text=...&filter=users&sessionid=...&steamid_user=false&page=1`, простой GET, в который надо лишь передать `text` (искомое значение) и `sessionid` (устанавливаемая сессия при первом заходе на сайт), все, у вас на руках JSON с данными. Учитесь анализировать сайты.